# How to deal with dependencies of generated sources in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, code-generation

For the last few days, I have been trying to get the code for a REST-API client being generated into my project using the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`. However, Maven fails in the `compile`-Phase as soon as it realizes that the third-party dependencies just introduced by the generated code have not been resolved yet. As the code generation itself works, my problem seems to be rather general and related to what's happening after code is being generated.

This is a sample POM, containing the copy-pasted contents of their own README on how to set the plugin up:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin-error-demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json</inputSpec>
              <generatorName>java</generatorName>
              <configOptions>
                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Running `mvn clean compile` should generate the sources, and it does. However, as soon as the `maven-compiler-plugin` kicks in right after the code is being generated, it sees newly introduced package and symbol references in the generated code and consequently fails.

So I have tried to figure out how to install said dependencies, AFTER generation, but BEFORE compilation, but completely failed to do so. I suspect I need to use the maven-depndencies-plugin, but due to my limited knowledge of Maven and even more limited knowledge of how its plugins work, I am completely lost. I have tried adding the `maven-dependency-plugin` to my POM, but Maven completely ignores it and does not run it at all. I have tried to bind the `resolve` goal to the `compile` phase to no avail.

I would have expected code generation to not be a too uncommon thing to do with Maven, so I am a bit surprised it is actually so hard to pull off. Am I on the right tracks here? What exactly am I missing to have those transitive dependencies introduced in the generated code installed before the compiler is trying to compile them?

Comment: Why not simply adding the needed dependencies to your already existing POM?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Because the openapi-generator-maven-plugin creates a full project with POM that already contains those dependency references and manually copying them to my main POM would kind of defeat the whole purpose of dynamically generating the code.

Comment: It does create a whole project? And you are putting it into `src/gen(java/main`? This is very puzzling ... and does not seem to be correct. You should only generate source files thag in turn are compiled in your project's lifecycle.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The configuration in the POM above is literally copy-pasted from their README. I'm not sure either if this is right or wrong, I just assumed it to work. Sorry, I'm not really experienced with this kind of stuff so I can't really see what's funky and what's not.

I was already wondering what's the purpose of the plugin at all if it generates a whole project

Comment: Btw: Source code generation is usually done into `target/generated` or similar, because the generation will be done each time you do a Maven build.

Comment: Ok, let me have a look. I will try out your POM snippet. (I am not familiar with the code generation you mentioned above ...) Could you provide me with a link to the README? Or better edit your question and place it there!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Generation does place it under `${root}/target/generated-sorces/openapi/`. There will be the POM and the `src` folder containing the folder structure you mentioned: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The README can be found [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin)

Comment: Did you see this below example. I have just now used it and it worked. This should work on an existing project also. As you can see this example has lot of java dependencies too. 

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/examples/java-client.xml

Comment: The generated source files (and the are only source files, not a whole project) depend on some libraries. I can see "okhttp3" for example. There are POM examples that show you which dependencies you need additionally in your POM.

Comment: Okay, so I DID need to manually put those dependencies into my root POM, then. Completely missed the examples at the botton of the README.. Feeling really stupid now. I sincerely apologize for wasting your time, then.
I have now copy-pasted the `dependencies` and `properties` from the generated POM and it works on the second time.
One question remains as to your last comment, though: What do you mean with "they are only sources, not a whole project"? I can see Gradle build files, a POM, docs, and all that being put into `target/generated-sources/openapi`. Isn't this a whole project?