# Openapi generator: how to import generated pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, openapi-generator

Suppose I have a project, where I generate the Api, Model and pom.xml from an openapi spec with openapi-generator plugin in the pom.xml. Handily this plugin generates the pom.xml with all the necessary dependencies.

[image]

**Question**: how do I import the generated pom into my parent pom? (without installing my generated pom into a local repository?).

I have seen solutions such as copying those dependencies into the parent pom, which feels hacky.

There seems to be a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576818/how-to-deal-with-dependencies-of-generated-sources-in-maven) on stackoverflow. But the answer is not very clear...

I have tried importing the generated pom.xml via dependency management, but maven complains, that it cannot find the generated pom in the local repo.
Parent pom.xml:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>generated_pom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Also: I know about the multi module approach, which requires me to setup a super pom.xml with packaging pom. This end up in three poms: generated, parent and super pom.xml. I would like to avoid that.

My Current pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <version>5.4.0</version>

                <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api/petstore.json</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/java/main</sourceFolder>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <library>resteasy</library>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>petstore</artifactId>
                            </configOptions>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <modelPackage>${project.groupId}.petstore.dto</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.petstore.api</apiPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I just copied the dependencies section from the generated Pom.xml. Could probably be scripted.

Comment: @Thorbjorn That is what I am doing now as well :/ but it feels unclean. 
The plugin generates a fully valid pom.xml only for devs to copy parts of it over (whether manually or by script)? I suspect there should be a cleaner solution

Comment: The OpenAPI generator creates a full Maven module, but Maven does not work well with modules being generated on the fly, so instead it is put inside `target/` and the source folder registered as generated sources.  Works well, except for the dependencies :)  A reasonable way would probably be if the openapi generator project used Bill-of-Material poms for the generated code which you could then just include, but that would require an upstream change.   For now, you may consider creating such a BOM in your project and compare XML to ensure that your dependency list is identical.

Comment: @Thorbjorn Thank you for the answer! Well, that is unfortunate... If chance and time arise, I will look into Gradle and see if that can satisfy my requirement. Until then it "copy paste" it is.